# Get selection positions of selected text drawed on static layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Drawing texts on a static layout like textview, and the texts are an item on a recyclerview. Normally, the textview has `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` functions but how to get the selection positions using a static layout?

Comment: I don't use textview because my data is huge, so drawing text only for performance gain.

Comment: So, you are using _StaticLayout_ for the text instead of _TextView_. Do you have text already selected in the _StaticLayout_? If so, how are you setting the selection?

Comment: Yes, I've the selected text without the seletion range, via recyclerview adapter position and its viewholder class. And the static layout has only setText(CharSequence text) method for drawing the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StaticLayout` should not be used in most of the cases. As stated in Android Developer Guides: "You should not need to use this class directly unless you are implementing your own widget or custom display object, or would be tempted to call Canvas.drawText() directly."

It is a very low-level component for drawing text. It is mostly used in specific situations e.g. when you want to draw text on bitmaps, or measure the size of the `TextView` before it is created, etc.

Therefore, it doesn't contain any API for handling text selection. That is implemented in `TextView` (which also uses `StaticLayout` under the hood).

Using just `TextView`s can in no situation affect performance of the app. Even with huge amounts of data, if you properly recycle `TextView`s in your `RecyclerView` using the mandatory `ViewHolder`, you will never have more `TextView`s than visible on the screen, only the text content will change as they get recycled/re-inserted, so there's no performance gain in avoiding them.

Comment: I know you're right, I thought it would have more performance, no need give up the textview, thanks.